# Sorting array of i by v[i]/w[i] in Go

Tags: sorting, go

I would like to sort an array of indices descendingly by `v[i]/w[i]` where `v` and `w` are two other arrays of integers. Here is what I have tried in Go:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "sort"

func main() {
    v := [3]int{5, 6, 3}
    w := [3]int{4, 5, 2}
    indices := make([]int, 3)
    for i := range indices {
        indices[i] = i
    }
    sort.Slice(indices, func(a, b int) bool {
        return float32(v[a])/float32(w[a]) > float32(v[b])/float32(w[b])
    })
    fmt.Println(indices)
}
```

I expect the output to be `[2,0,1]` because *3/2 > 5/4 > 6/5* but the actual output is `[0,2,1]`. Could anyone help me find the where the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: This is a lot easier if you *don't use parallel arrays* to begin with. They usually complicate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not mutate v and w arrays which can be expensive, we can just add another level of indirection into the Less function

```
sort.Slice(indices, func(a, b int) bool {
        return float32(v[indices[a]])/float32(w[indices[a]]) > float32(v[indices[b]])/float32(w[indices[b]])
    })
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/p-GviDZq2b_V)

Comment: You have the wrong comparator here (through correct in the playground). Your original answer also had no description of what you were doing. Otherwise this is a good solution.

Comment: Turns out I misunderstood the meanings of the args of comparison function (a and b are index of items to be compared instead of the items to be compared). I think you are downvoted because you make the order wrong. Thank you for the solution though, because it's clean to read and short to type.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by definition moves items you're sorting around in the slice, therefore changing their respective indexes. However you are not moving the actual values you are sorting, which are in `w` and `v`, only the `indices` slice.

Since the `indices` slice contains the sorted "indices", you can use that to lookup the actual value for comparison.

```
sort.Slice(indices, func(i, j int) bool {
    return float64(v[indices[i]])/float64(w[indices[i]]) > float64(v[indices[j]])/float64(w[indices[j]])
})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6oFBM27bVR-

Or you could implement a type to sort all 3 values at once for example:

```
type indexSorter struct {
    indices, w, v []int
}

func (a indexSorter) Len() int { return len(a.indices) }
func (a indexSorter) Swap(i, j int) {
    a.indices[i], a.indices[j] = a.indices[j], a.indices[i]
    a.w[i], a.w[j] = a.w[j], a.w[i]
    a.v[i], a.v[j] = a.v[j], a.v[i]
}
func (a indexSorter) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return float64(a.v[i])/float64(a.w[i]) > float64(a.v[i])/float64(a.w[j])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/EFUkHWgjo5U

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should have read the docs more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the sort function changes the indices while it is sorting but your accompanying arrays v and w remain constant.

The best way to do what you want is to create a single array with v and w both contained in a struct and then order that array.